# how to add validations in dropdowns in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I have 2 dropdown fields namely role and type. Now in role if I choose directory type then only I will be able to select from type dropdown else not. How to write validations for this in Ruby-on rails.

Comment: welcome to SO, I would like to suggest you upload your source code (part of where you had problem) so others can read and help you

Comment: For that you need to write javascript. Assuming you are using jQuery, check https://api.jquery.com/change and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/